# Disappearing Windows in GNOME 3

Tags: 12.10, gnome, lenovo

I've been searching like mad, but haven't been able to find anyone with a similar problem, so here it goes.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 with GNOME 3 on my Lenovo T400.  Almost once every day or two, I'll have a couple windows open, and all of a sudden, they'll disappear. The only thing that's left is my background with the top panel from GNOME. (And I think it's grayed out a bit, like something's overlaid on the backgroud.)

If I hit the Windows super key or click "Activities", they'll all show up, as usual. However, the favorites menu along with the search bar will be missing. As soon as I hit the super key to return, the windows disappear again, leaving me with only the desktop.  Similarly, Alt+Tab brings shows me the different windows (as I have Coverflow installed), but then nothing once I let go.

Any similar problems, suggestions, references?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what the root cause might be, but as a workaround I'd suggest hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (to bring up the "run" dialog), enter `r` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will restart Gnome shell, but leave your applications running.