# In GNOME 3 sometimes windows disappear, but "restarting" GNOME won't help

Tags: 18.04, gnome-classic

I am having an issue that - on the surface - is quite similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/235443/11316). Alas, I have tried the suggested remedy of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing `r` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart GNOME, but that doesn't make the programs reappear.

I have had this mainly with programs that aren't "native". For example running KeePass 2.43 under the Mono runtime and the [Nitrokey app via the PPA](https://www.nitrokey.com/download/ubuntu).

A handful of times I had the impression that I had invoked some kind of keyboard shortcut, but I cannot find the window for these apps on any of the workspaces nor via <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>). Also, the dash doesn't show the apps as running (blue indicator in my case) and instead starts a new instance when I click there.

What gives? How can I locate the window(s) for these apps after they disappear, when `pgrep -a ...` clearly shows running instances of these apps (but no windows seem to be accessible from the GNOME desktop).

I am using `vanilla-gnome-desktop` with GNOME Classic on Ubuntu 18.04 (fully up-to-date).

Comment: Is it possible that although the application may still be *running* that mono has stopped communicating correctly with Gnome? I'm not sure what the cause of this could possibly be. By "fully up-to-date," I'm assuming you have purged and reinstalled all the 'problem programs?'

Comment: @David as for `nitrokey-app` that assumption is true. KeePass doesn't come packaged this way (at least not in a recent enough version: `2.38+dfsg-1` versus the mentioned `2.43`). It runs simply via Mono. It's very well possible that it has "stopped" communicating. But how do I diagnose such situation then and how can I "recover" from it? As an example, the `nitrokey-app` grabs a particular device and so _killing_ it isn't exactly the most prudent course of action.

Comment: From what I can tell, and by the fact that this is *so* app-specific, it may be a flaw inside of the programming for the individual programs themselves. If nothing else, if someone more skilled than I cannot help you in a few days, I would recommend filing bug reports

Comment: @David wait? If this affects at least two different apps with similar symptoms how does that suggest it's app-specific? I mean, sure _it doesn't rule out_ the possibility, but I can't see at this point how this is app-specific. Especially given given one is Mono/.NET-based and the other Qt5-based (`nitrokey-app`). But yeah, I can resort to filing defect tickets in a few days. If nothing else the devs may have seen reports of the behavior and are aware of workarounds/fixes. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I should rephrase. It may be a problem with the way the version performs on your version of Ubuntu.. Depending on how recently these programs were released, development may have been aimed at 19.XX, but ported to 1X.XX for backwards compatibility. It may not be a single line of code in these programs that breaks it, but rather a similarity in the programmers' personal choices on **how** they program

Comment: @David ah, that _does_ make perfect sense. You're right. Both are newer. With Mono I'd expect fewer problems, though. But for `nitrokey-app` this is a very valid point indeed. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Does the window of these programs appear nowhere in the Overview? Even if a program laucher does not make it to the Alt+tab switcher or the Dash, it still should be somewhere in the overview. Also windows of minimized programs appear there.

Comment: @vanadium correct, these windows appear nowhere. Unless the Overview is different from one of the facilities I mentioned (in which case, please direct me how to see it).